# Playing against a tablebase online

Tags: tablebases, websites

I'm looking for a website where I can play endgames against a 6-man or 7-man tablebase. These tablebases are too large for me to install locally. I'm aware that Lichess allows users to view tablebase result. However, I'm trying to practice endgames against the tablebase without looking up the moves and entering them myself, like in the [Browne vs. BELLE match](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawnless_chess_endgame#Browne_versus_Belle). Lichess's engines currently don't use the tablebases when they play against users.

Does anyone know an existing website that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the Syzygy tablebases [here](https://syzygy-tables.info/), and if you cover up what the tablebase tells you to do, you can "play" against it. Every time it's the tablebase's turn to move, pick the move that it lists at the top.

Comment: Seems to be the best option for now, I'll keep searching for a site that allows the best responses to be played automatically.